# Why does Bochs crash on simple mov instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bootloader, bochs

I'm building a small operating system and was using Qemu before which was working properly. Now I'm stuck on a Windows 10 machine and Qemu doesn't work well with GDB on this machine. I thought I'd try Bochs or Virtual box instead.

The problem is that with both of these I end up with crashes created by simple mov instructions.

The problematic instructions aim at testing the A20 gate by writing and reading memory and by comparing the equality of registers.

```
mov dword [0x112345], 0x1234     ;crash happens here
mov dword [0x012345], 0x2345
mov eax, [0x112345]
mov ebx, [0x012345]
cmp eax, ebx
jne a20_enabled

a20_enabled:
```

This code compiles fine using nasm. It runs fine on Qemu as well. I add the whole code for reference.

```
org 0x7c00

bits 16

mov ah, 0x00
mov al, 0x03
int 0x10

xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax

cli

lgdt[gdtr]

mov eax, cr0
or al, 1
mov cr0, eax

jmp 0x08:protectedMode      ;0x08 = 1000b, 1 for segment selector
                            ;0 for gdt not ldt and 00 for privilege
                            
bits 32

protectedMode:

mov dword [0x112345], 0x1234
mov dword [0x012345], 0x2345
mov eax, [0x112345]
mov ebx, [0x012345]
cmp eax, ebx
jne a20_enabled

a20_enabled:

halt:
hlt
jmp halt

gdt_start:
        dq 0x0
gdt_code:
        dw 0xFFFF   ;limit 0-15
        dw 0x0      ;base 0-15
        db 0x0      ;base 16-23 
        db 10011010b    ;pr, privi (2), s, ex, dc, rw, ac 
        db 11001111b    ;gr, sz, limit 16-19
        db 0x0      ;base 24-31
gdt_data:
        dw 0xFFFF
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 10010010b
        db 11001111b
        db 0x0  
gdtr:
        dw 24
        dd gdt_start

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Bochs error log is the following which clearly points to the faulty instruction and then triple faults which resets the CPU.

```
00000000000i[      ] reading configuration from C:\Users\E01GEN_E01CSA26268\Documents\bootloader\bochsrc.bxrc
00000000000i[      ] installing win32 module as the Bochs GUI
00000000000i[      ] Bochs x86 Emulator 2.6.10
00000000000i[      ]   Built from SVN snapshot on December 1, 2019
00000000000i[      ] Compiled on Dec  1 2019 at 17:34:11
00000000000i[      ] System configuration
00000000000i[      ]   processors: 1 (cores=1, HT threads=1)
00000000000i[      ]   A20 line support: yes
00000000000i[      ] IPS is set to 4000000
00000000000i[      ] CPU configuration
00000000000i[      ]   SMP support: no
00000000000i[      ]   level: 6
00000000000i[      ]   APIC support: xapic
00000000000i[      ]   FPU support: yes
00000000000i[      ]   MMX support: yes
00000000000i[      ]   3dnow! support: no
00000000000i[      ]   SEP support: yes
00000000000i[      ]   SIMD support: sse2
00000000000i[      ]   XSAVE support: no
00000000000i[      ]   AES support: no
00000000000i[      ]   SHA support: no
00000000000i[      ]   MOVBE support: no
00000000000i[      ]   ADX support: no
00000000000i[      ]   x86-64 support: yes
00000000000i[      ]   1G paging support: no
00000000000i[      ]   MWAIT support: yes
00000000000i[      ]   VMX support: 1
00000000000i[      ] Optimization configuration
00000000000i[      ]   RepeatSpeedups support: yes
00000000000i[      ]   Fast function calls: yes
00000000000i[      ]   Handlers Chaining speedups: no
00000000000i[      ] Devices configuration
00000000000i[      ]   PCI support: i440FX i430FX i440BX
00000000000i[      ]   Networking support: NE2000 E1000
00000000000i[      ]   Sound support: SB16 ES1370
00000000000i[      ]   USB support: UHCI OHCI EHCI xHCI
00000000000i[      ]   VGA extension support: vbe cirrus voodoo
00000000000i[MEM0  ] allocated memory at 0000017FD4571040. after alignment, vector=0000017FD4572000
00000000000i[MEM0  ] 32,00MB
00000000000i[MEM0  ] mem block size = 0x00020000, blocks=256
00000000000i[MEM0  ] rom at 0xfffe0000/131072 ('C:\Program Files\Bochs-2.6.11/BIOS-bochs-latest')
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DEV   ] i440FX PMC present at device 0, function 0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DEV   ] PIIX3 PCI-to-ISA bridge present at device 1, function 0
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[CMOS  ] Using local time for initial clock
00000000000i[CMOS  ] Setting initial clock to: Thu Sep 17 20:25:10 2020 (time0=1600388710)
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DMA   ] channel 4 used by cascade
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[MEM0  ] Register memory access handlers: 0x0000000a0000 - 0x0000000bffff
00000000000i[VGA   ] interval=200000, mode=realtime
00000000000i[VGA   ] VSYNC using standard mode
00000000000i[MEM0  ] Register memory access handlers: 0x0000e0000000 - 0x0000e0ffffff
00000000000i[BXVGA ] VBE Bochs Display Extension Enabled
00000000000i[WINGUI] Desktop Window dimensions: 1680 x 1050
00000000000i[WINGUI] Number of Mouse Buttons = 8
00000000000i[WINGUI] IME disabled
00000000000i[MEM0  ] rom at 0xc0000/41984 ('C:\Program Files\Bochs-2.6.11/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest')
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DMA   ] channel 2 used by Floppy Drive
00000000000i[FLOPPY] Using boot sequence disk, none, none
00000000000i[FLOPPY] Floppy boot signature check is enabled
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DEV   ] ACPI Controller present at device 1, function 3
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'hpet' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[HPET  ] initializing HPET
00000000000i[MEM0  ] Register memory access handlers: 0x0000fed00000 - 0x0000fed003ff
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[IOAPIC] initializing I/O APIC
00000000000i[MEM0  ] Register memory access handlers: 0x0000fec00000 - 0x0000fec00fff
00000000000i[IOAPIC] IOAPIC enabled (base address = 0xfec00000)
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[KBD   ] will paste characters every 400 keyboard ticks
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[HD    ] HD on ata0-0: 'C:\Users\E01GEN_E01CSA26268\Documents\bootloader\disk.img', 'flat' mode
00000000000i[IMG   ] hd_size: 10490880
00000000000i[HD    ] ata0-0: using specified geometry: CHS=20/16/63 (sector size=512)
00000000000i[HD    ] ata0-0: extra data outside of CHS address range
00000000000i[HD    ] translation on ata0-0 set to 'none'
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DEV   ] PIIX3 PCI IDE controller present at device 1, function 1
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PCSPK ] Using lowlevel sound support for output
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PAR   ] parallel port 1 at 0x0378 irq 7
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[SER   ] com1 at 0x03f8 irq 4 (mode: null)
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] init_dev of 'usb_uhci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[DEV   ] USB UHCI present at device 1, function 2
00000000000i[UHCI  ] USB UHCI initialized
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'usb_uhci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'hpet' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] register state of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[SYS   ] bx_pc_system_c::Reset(HARDWARE) called
00000000000i[CPU0  ] cpu hardware reset
00000000000i[APIC0 ] allocate APIC id=0 (MMIO enabled) to 0x0000fee00000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000000]: 00000005 756e6547 6c65746e 49656e69
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000001]: 00000633 00010800 00002028 1fcbfbff
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000002]: 00410601 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000003]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000004]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000005]: 00000040 00000040 00000003 00000020
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000000]: 80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000001]: 00000000 00000000 00000101 2a100000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000002]: 20202020 20202020 20202020 6e492020
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000003]: 286c6574 50202952 69746e65 52286d75
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000004]: 20342029 20555043 20202020 00202020
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000005]: 01ff01ff 01ff01ff 40020140 40020140
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000006]: 00000000 42004200 02008140 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000007]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000008]: 00003028 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000000i[CPU0  ] CPU Features supported:
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            x87
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            486ni
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            pentium_ni
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            p6ni
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            mmx
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            debugext
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            vme
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            pse
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            pae
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            pge
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            pse36
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            mtrr
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            pat
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            sysenter_sysexit
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            clflush
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            sse
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            sse2
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            mwait
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            vmx
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            longmode
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            lm_lahf_sahf
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            nx
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            cmpxhg16b
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            rdtscp
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            ffxsr
00000000000i[CPU0  ]            x2apic
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'hpet' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[PLUGIN] reset of 'usb_uhci' plugin device by virtual method
00000000000i[      ] set SIGINT handler to bx_debug_ctrlc_handler
Next at t=0
(0) [0x0000fffffff0] f000:fff0 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0xf000:e05b          ; ea5be000f0
<bochs:1> c
00000004662i[BIOS  ] $Revision: 13752 $ $Date: 2019-12-30 14:16:18 +0100 (Mon, 30 Dec 2019) $
00000318050i[KBD   ] reset-disable command received
00000320827i[BIOS  ] Starting rombios32
00000321265i[BIOS  ] Shutdown flag 0
00000321855i[BIOS  ] ram_size=0x02000000
00000322277i[BIOS  ] ram_end=32MB
00000362837i[BIOS  ] Found 1 cpu(s)
00000376489i[BIOS  ] bios_table_addr: 0x000f9db8 end=0x000fcc00
00000602720i[WINGUI] dimension update x=720 y=400 fontheight=16 fontwidth=9 bpp=8
00000704310i[PCI   ] i440FX PMC write to PAM register 59 (TLB Flush)
00001032240i[P2ISA ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQA# set to 0x0b
00001032259i[P2ISA ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQB# set to 0x09
00001032278i[P2ISA ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQC# set to 0x0b
00001032297i[P2ISA ] PCI IRQ routing: PIRQD# set to 0x09
00001032307i[P2ISA ] write: ELCR2 = 0x0a
00001033077i[BIOS  ] PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0a
00001046749i[BIOS  ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x00: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x1237 class=0x0600
00001049062i[BIOS  ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x08: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7000 class=0x0601
00001051214i[BIOS  ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x09: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7010 class=0x0101
00001051449i[PIDE  ] BAR #4: i/o base address = 0xc000
00001052065i[BIOS  ] region 4: 0x0000c000
00001054107i[BIOS  ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x0a: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7020 class=0x0c03
00001054320i[UHCI  ] BAR #4: i/o base address = 0xc020
00001054936i[BIOS  ] region 4: 0x0000c020
00001055070i[UHCI  ] new IRQ line = 9
00001056992i[BIOS  ] PCI: bus=0 devfn=0x0b: vendor_id=0x8086 device_id=0x7113 class=0x0680
00001057236i[ACPI  ] new IRQ line = 11
00001057250i[ACPI  ] new IRQ line = 9
00001057277i[ACPI  ] new PM base address: 0xb000
00001057291i[ACPI  ] new SM base address: 0xb100
00001057319i[PCI   ] setting SMRAM control register to 0x4a
00001221412i[CPU0  ] Enter to System Management Mode
00001221412i[CPU0  ] enter_system_management_mode: temporary disable VMX while in SMM mode
00001221422i[CPU0  ] RSM: Resuming from System Management Mode
00001385443i[PCI   ] setting SMRAM control register to 0x0a
00001412159i[BIOS  ] MP table addr=0x000f9e90 MPC table addr=0x000f9dc0 size=0xc8
00001414030i[BIOS  ] SMBIOS table addr=0x000f9ea0
00001416216i[BIOS  ] ACPI tables: RSDP addr=0x000f9fd0 ACPI DATA addr=0x01ff0000 size=0xff8
00001419463i[BIOS  ] Firmware waking vector 0x1ff00cc
00001421943i[PCI   ] i440FX PMC write to PAM register 59 (TLB Flush)
00001422666i[BIOS  ] bios_table_cur_addr: 0x000f9ff4
00001551537i[VBIOS ] VGABios $Id: vgabios.c 226 2020-01-02 21:36:23Z vruppert $
00001551608i[BXVGA ] VBE known Display Interface b0c0
00001551640i[BXVGA ] VBE known Display Interface b0c5
00001554283i[VBIOS ] VBE Bios $Id: vbe.c 228 2020-01-02 23:09:02Z vruppert $
00001901970i[BIOS  ] ata0-0: PCHS=20/16/63 translation=none LCHS=20/16/63
00005349148i[BIOS  ] IDE time out
00017404779i[BIOS  ] Booting from 0000:7c00
00017466534e[CPU0  ] write_virtual_checks(): write beyond limit, r/w
00017466534e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x0d)
00017466534e[CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPU is in protected mode (active)
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CS.mode = 32 bit
00017466534i[CPU0  ] SS.mode = 16 bit
00017466534i[CPU0  ] EFER   = 0x00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | EAX=60000011  EBX=00000000  ECX=00090000  EDX=00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | ESP=00008000  EBP=00000000  ESI=000e0000  EDI=0000ffac
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | IOPL=0 id vip vif ac vm RF nt of df if tf sf zf af PF cf
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
00017466534i[CPU0  ] |  CS:0008( 0001| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00017466534i[CPU0  ] |  DS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00017466534i[CPU0  ] |  SS:0010( 0005| 0|  0) 00000100 0000ffff 0 0
00017466534i[CPU0  ] |  ES:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00017466534i[CPU0  ] |  FS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00017466534i[CPU0  ] |  GS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | EIP=00007c44 (00007c44)
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | CR0=0x60000011 CR2=0x00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] | CR3=0x00000000 CR4=0x00000000
(0).[17466534] [0x000000007c44] 0008:0000000000007c44 (unk. ctxt): mov dword ptr ds:0x00112345, 0x00001234 ; c7054523110034120000
00017466534e[CPU0  ] exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting
00017466534i[SYS   ] bx_pc_system_c::Reset(HARDWARE) called
00017466534i[CPU0  ] cpu hardware reset
00017466534i[APIC0 ] allocate APIC id=0 (MMIO enabled) to 0x0000fee00000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000000]: 00000005 756e6547 6c65746e 49656e69
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000001]: 00000633 00010800 00002028 1fcbfbff
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000002]: 00410601 00000000 00000000 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000003]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000004]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x00000005]: 00000040 00000040 00000003 00000020
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000000]: 80000008 00000000 00000000 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000001]: 00000000 00000000 00000101 2a100000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000002]: 20202020 20202020 20202020 6e492020
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000003]: 286c6574 50202952 69746e65 52286d75
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000004]: 20342029 20555043 20202020 00202020
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000005]: 01ff01ff 01ff01ff 40020140 40020140
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000006]: 00000000 42004200 02008140 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000007]: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPUID[0x80000008]: 00003028 00000000 00000000 00000000
00017466534i[CPU0  ] CPU Features supported:
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            x87
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            486ni
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            pentium_ni
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            p6ni
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            mmx
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            debugext
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            vme
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            pse
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            pae
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            pge
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            pse36
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            mtrr
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            pat
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            sysenter_sysexit
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            clflush
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            sse
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            sse2
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            mwait
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            vmx
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            longmode
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            lm_lahf_sahf
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            nx
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            cmpxhg16b
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            rdtscp
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            ffxsr
00017466534i[CPU0  ]            x2apic
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pci' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pci2isa' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'cmos' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'dma' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pic' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pit' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'vga' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'floppy' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'acpi' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'hpet' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'ioapic' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'keyboard' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'harddrv' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'pci_ide' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'unmapped' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'biosdev' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'speaker' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'extfpuirq' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'parallel' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'serial' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'gameport' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'iodebug' plugin device by virtual method
00017466534i[PLUGIN] reset of 'usb_uhci' plugin device by virtual method
Next at t=17466535
(0) [0x0000fffffff0] f000:fff0 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0xf000:e05b          ; ea5be000f0
```

Comment: Don't you need to load DS with the selector of your data segment?

Comment: It works with ds set to 0x10. Why does it work on QEMU without. Thanks though.

Comment: Because QEMU's emulator takes shortcuts and may omit certain checks to improve speed of the emulator. If you are on a KVM enabled Linux system then pass the option `-enable-kvm` to QEMU and you may observe the faults you would normally not see.

Comment: `gdt_start` should be aligned by putting an `align 8` directive before it.

Comment: @ecm Why is that????

Comment: @user123: Supposedly 8 or even 16 byte alignment may be needed by some processors. Eg https://git.rigado.com/vesta/u-boot-2015.04/commit/58c7a6751dd0978172741503b4dc0c6b23a60b33#6d6390ea995681dbcc5bbb8cf796286665a9c1ac_90_89 and https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?p=165387